# automated mechanism to open the Oracle SQL developer in my desktop, every monday Morning at 01:00 am and run an sql query in it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, scheduler

I am using  Oracle SQL developer 4.1.3.20.
I want an automated mechanism to open the Oracle SQL developer in my desktop -- every monday Morning at 01:00 am , connect to a DB and run an sql query in it. 
I don't have the privilege to create a scheduler job in the oracle DB. I only have privilege to execute a read only query. 
The Query takes long time to execute (more than 2 hours due to the size of the DB). I want the Query results to be ready in my desktop, when  i come to office on Monday morning.
Please let me know how to do that. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Just a thought - don't give up on tuning the query. I've seen many 2hr queries tuned down to 2 seconds.

Comment: You can follow @thatjeffsmith's advice and do what you want.  What you're asking to do, though, does not appear to be sensible.  Surely, if you have a need to get a data set every Monday it would make sense for this to be a report that your reporting system (which undoubtedly has facilities to automate and deliver reports) can run rather than something that lives on your local machine.  Particularly when corporate desktops generally get rebooted on the weekends for things like patches and updates and you're trying to run something at 1am.

Comment: @JustinCave a lot of people have this problem and this seems to be the answer, but i agree, you need a system driven solution - a report, or even a MV, or gosh forbid tune the query

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Yeah.  I've just dealt with way too many shadow IT "you see, Bob runs this Excel spreadsheet that queries a database then writes the data to an Access database on Carol's machine where there is some VB that further processes the data and loads it into a spreadsheet on Don's machine but Don has no idea how the spreadsheet actually works because it's been written by a succession of interns and what comes out in the end is the Really Important KPI that we report to the board.  The KPI on your new report doesn't match.  Why is your report wrong"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. There is no way to tell SQL Developer to start, connect, and run a query from the CLI.

However, you could use the SQL program in your SQL Developer / bin directory, and script SQLcl to connect and run your query. You could have it spool the results to a CSV or formatted text report.

You can get a newer version of SQL Developer that ships with SQLcl, or go [download it separately](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html).

You on Windows, Mac, or Linux? I can try to share a bash/bat script as an example.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 machine.spooling the results to a CSV is a great idea. can you please post the bat script to do that

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you you can open the “scheduled tasks” or “task scheduler” depending on what OS version you have and define a new task there. Must you use SQL Developer or can you use a Sql*Plus client and just run a predefined query and spool the results to a file?